# Object output and input issues, only prints the first line on the input

Tags: java, serialization, object, objectoutputstream, objectinputstream

I'm making a chat server for a class and am having issue logging messages for offline users.  The data appends to the logfile as an object, it grows in size as you log more.  When I login as the user who received a message it only returns the first message sent.  I've spent a lot of time with this can can't figure out what I'm missing.

**The input:**

```
 if (exists)
    ObjectInputStream in = null;

    try{
    in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(uLog));
    Message msgs;
    Object obj = null;
        while ((obj = in.readObject()) != null)
        {
        msgs = (Message) obj;
        user.writeToUser(new Message("POST", "Offline Message from",  msgs.getTo() +" "+ msgs.getText()));
        }

    in.close();

           }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
  System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
  }

  boolean success = uLog.delete();

  if (!success)
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Delete: deletion failed");
  }
```

**The Output:**

```
if(!usersList.getUserByName(msg.getTo()).getOnlineStatus())
{
   ObjectOutputStream out;
   try{
   out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(msg.getTo() + ".log", true));
   user.writeToUser(new Message("PRIVATE", user.getUserName(), msg.getTo(), msg.getText()));
   out.writeObject(new Message("PRIVATE", msg.getTo(), user.getUserName(), msg.getText()));
   out.close();
   }
catch (IOException e){
System.out.println("Exception");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can just append to an ObjectOutputStream like that. I think it would be possible if you do this:

For output, keep appending messages as you do now.

For input, open file as a byte input stream. Wrap this in a ObjectInputStream. When that object input stream has no more date, discard it, check the original byte input stream for more data, if it has more, then create a new ObjectInputStream and read data from that. Repeat until no more data exists in byte input stream.

There might be issues with ObjectInputStream consuming data not belonging to it.

Comment: I'm not sure how to take a byte input and wrap it into an ObjectInputStream.  Any tips on this?

Comment: You are doing it, The FileInputStream is a InputStream for bytes. Just keep you handle to it.